# Refresh the control of a label in SWT

Tags: java, widget, swt, grid-layout, composite

I wrote the following code which creates a small "table" (it's not really a table, rather two labels stuck together).

```
private void createOptionsPrefs(final ExpandBar parent) {
        final Composite optionsPrefsComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        optionsPrefsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(totalColumns, true));

    /** Showing one of the non table labels that must not be deleted **/
    final boolean dateEnabled = PM.getInstance().getStringPM(PT.DATE));
    final String dateStatus = dateEnabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled";

    Label dateLabel, dateValueLabel;
    dateLabel = new Label(optionsPrefsComposite, SWT.NONE);
    dateLabel.setLayoutData(descLabelGridData);
    dateLabel.setText(PT.DATE.getExplanationLabelText());

    dateValueLabel = new Label(optionsPrefsComposite, SWT.NONE);
    dateValueLabel.setLayoutData(valueLabelGridData);
    dateValueLabel.setText(dateStatus);
    valueOfVariableOrDependentWigets.put(dateStatus, dateValueLabel);

    /** more code here - other labels **/

    final GridData descLabelGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, horizontalSpanForClioCommandPrefs, 1);
    final GridData valueLabelGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, totalColumns - horizontalSpanForClioCommandPrefs, 1);

    final Label nameTitleLabel = new Label(optionsPrefsComposite, SWT.None);
    nameTitleLabel.setText("Custom Name");
    nameTitleLabel.setLayoutData(descLabelGridData);

    final Label commandTitleLabel = new Label(optionsPrefsComposite, SWT.None);
    commandTitleLabel.setText("Value");
    commandTitleLabel.setLayoutData(valueLabelGridData);

    for (final OptionsAll option : PM.getInstance().getOptionsList()) {
        final Label nameLabel = new Label(optionsPrefsComposite, SWT.None);
        nameLabel.setText(option.getName());
        nameLabel.setLayoutData(descLabelGridData);

        final Label commandLabel = new Label(optionsPrefsComposite, SWT.None);
        commandLabel.setText(option.getValue());
        commandLabel.setLayoutData(valueLabelGridData);
    }


    createExpandItem(optionsPrefsComposite, "Reporting Options", com.ui.Activator.getDefault().getImageRegistry().get(IImageKeys.LOGO.getPath()));
}
```

This table could be updated in the same UI location. I mean that the user can feel the table (in other tab) and it should update this "table". I want to create a automatic refresh method which will dispose that table (not the Composite) and add a new one.
At first I though to write the following function:

```
private void refreshOptions() {
    bar.getItem(optionExpandItemIndex).getControl().dispose();

    final Composite optionsComposite = generateOptionList(bar);
    bar.getItem(optionExpandItemIndex).setControl(optionsComposite);
}
```

But it will dispose from the control and not the table. Is it possible to generate a new table, remove the old one and add a new one?
Maybe to add some event listener? I'm quite new to `SWT` so I'm looking for an idea of how to solve it.

Comment: Also you are using the same `GridData` on multiple controls - **this is not allowed**. You must create a new `GridData` for every control.

Comment: This would be a lot easier using a real Table so you could just replace its contents.

Comment: @greg-449 I can't replace it because its the format of the box. Is it possible to replace it? Will fix the "GridData" part (why btw its not allowed?)

Comment: Grid layout stores information about the layout of a control in the GridData. Using the same GridData for multiple controls results in the layout not working properly.